# json_encode returns array as a string when posting data with jquery.get()

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays

Hello I have a problem with my ajax request in jquery.

When I use my get request without sending any data the response is as expected, I receive my array and can access the values:

```
$.get(
    loadUrl,
    function(data) {
        useReturnData(data);
    },
    "json"
);

function useReturnData(data){
    leftPlayer = data;
    alert(leftPlayer[4]);
};
```

This works as expected and I recieve my value of "528" being my leftPlayer[4] value.

But when I change my request to send a piece of data to php in the request like so:

```
$.get(
    loadUrl,
    { type: "left" })
    .done(function(data) {
        useReturnData(data);
    },
    "json"
);

function useReturnData(data){
    leftPlayer = data;
    alert(leftPlayer[4]);
};
```

My data received seems to be in string format to javascript.
My alert prints "5" (the 4th character if the array was a string)

When alerting leftPlayer. I find that in the first request in which I send no data the variable is printed as: 355,355,355,355,528,etc...

Whereas in the second request in which I DO send data it prints as:

[355,355,355,355,528,etc...]

Notice the []. It isn't recognised as an array.

The php file it accesses has absolutely no changes in each request, as I am testing at the moment. The data sent isn't even used in the php file at the moment.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: You should be passing the `"json"` parameter to the `$.get()` function, but you're passing it to the `.done()` function.

Comment: Ah I see.. I tried using:

Comment: $.get(
  loadUrl,
  { type: "left" },
  "json")
  .done(function(data) {
   useReturnData(data);
  }
 ); - but no change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed my problem.

Like what "nnnnnn" said in his comment I'm passing my "json" parameter to the .done() function instead of the $.get() function.

I couldn't seem to get it to correctly view it as JSON though so I used the easiest method:

```
$.getJSON(
    loadUrl,
    { type: "left" },
    function(data) {
        useReturnData(data);
    }
);

function useReturnData(data){
    leftPlayer = data;
    alert(leftPlayer[4]);
};
```

Using $.getJSON instead does like what it says and expects JSON to be returned as default.